# GridView performance / number of columns

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a `GridView` with a `BaseAdapter` attached to it. I tried to keep the `getView()` as straight as possible and I'm using the `ViewHolder` pattern. 
The `GridView` has one column in portrait mode and 2 columns in landscape mode and there is a vast difference in performance. With 1 column, the list scrolls very smoothly, whereas with 2 columns, it lags and stutters.

Are there any additional performance tipps for `GridView`?

As for the getView method, I tried not doing anything except for setting some text on the list item, even when not setting an image it stutters in 2 column mode. 
Using a Nexus 10 btw, so hardware can't be the issue.

EDIT: This is my `getView` method:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    checkLoadMore(position);

    final Item item = combinedGsr.getItems().get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_result, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.Tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.Tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.Tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.Tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        holder.Btn = (CheckableImageButton) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
        holder.Iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.Root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
        holder.ImageRoot = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageroot);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.Tv1.setText(item.getTitle());

    String preis = item.getPrice();

    if (preis.contains("Kaufpreis") && preis.length() > 10) {

        String ps = preis.substring(10, preis.length());
        Log.d("LAY", "String " + ps);

        String ptext = "Kaufpreis: " + "<font color='#000000\'>" + ps
                + "</font>";

        holder.Tv2.setText(Html.fromHtml(ptext));

    }

    else {
        holder.Tv2.setText(preis);
    }

    String land = item.getCountry();

    if (land.length() > 15) {

        String es = land.substring(15, land.length());
        String ltext = "Land: " + "<font color='#000000\'>" + es        // tried not using it, makes no difference
                + "</font>";
        holder.Tv3.setText(Html.fromHtml(ltext));
    }

    else {
        holder.Tv3.setText("");
    }

    holder.Tv4.setText(item.getLocation());

    String nurl = Tools.convertImageUrl(item.getThumbnailUrl()); // this is just some regex, tried not using it, makes no difference

    displayImage(nurl, holder.Iv, holder.ImageRoot);        // This uses the UniversalImageLoader library to display an Image

    int pad = holder.Root.getPaddingBottom();

    if (GlobalApp.favItemsContain(item.getGuid())) {        // I had this in suspicion, tried not using it, makes no difference

        holder.Btn.setChecked(true);
        holder.Root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listitem_bg_green);

    }

    else {

        holder.Btn.setChecked(false);
        holder.Root.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listitem_bg_gray);

    }

    holder.Root.setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);

    holder.Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String guid = item.getGuid();

            int[] location = new int[2];
            v.getLocationOnScreen(location);

            if (GlobalApp.favItems(guid)) {
                GlobalApp.removeFromFavItems(guid);

                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(
                        ctx,
                        ctx.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.item_entfernt),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, location[0],
                        location[1]);

                toast.show();
            }

            else {
                GlobalApp.addToFavItems(guid, item);

                if (toast != null) {
                    toast.cancel();
                }

                toast = Toast.makeText(
                        ctx,
                        ctx.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.item_gesetzt),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, location[0],
                        location[1]);

                toast.show();
            }

        }
    });



    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `getView()` method?

Comment: It' sin the question now.